# How do I delete common elements from one column A that are present in another column B in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How to delete common things (str, int, float) in one column that I also find in another column?

Suppose I have in a dataframe :

```
colA                              colBB            
eat a nice icecream               icecream            
I love to walk a lot              walk , to          
the city Paris is super           Paris, super  
        .
        .
        .
```

I would like to have this result :

```
colA                    colBB          
eat a nice              icecream          
I love a lot            walk , to           
the city is             Paris, super 
        .
        .
        .
```

And this applied to every row in a big pandas Df.

I did lower the text and tokenized the sentences already but after that I am blocked for the application...

Thank you

Comment: try something like `df['ColA'] = df.apply(lambda row: [x for x in row['colA'] if x not in row['colBB'], axis=1)`

Comment: (assuming that the items in colA are already lists of strings)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

code to make a df:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'colA': ['eat a nice icecream', 'I love to walk a lot','the city Paris is super'], 
    'colB': ['icecream', 'walk , to', 'Paris, super']})
```

```
    colA                      colB
0   eat a nice icecream       icecream
1   I love to walk a lot      walk , to
2   the city Paris is super   Paris, super
```

code to get expected output:

```py
df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([y.strip() for y in x[0].split(' ') if y.strip() not in x[1].split(' ')]), axis=1)
```

Comment: Also, you can modify this by removing punctuations first in string